# server copy & paste images in website

Tags: remote-desktop, images, copy-paste

I want to copy images generated by a software installed in windows server 2008 and paste in the website through Ctrl+C and Ctrl+v commands. I am facing problems and I could not paste the image in the website. The windows server is accessed through Remote Desktop Connection. Kindly help me in fixing this error

Comment: You can copy and paste the image *file* from a Remote desktop session to your local computer. Then, you can use the file the way you normally would.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am doing now. kindly suggest me how i can directly do the copy-paste between the servers directly

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with the file, but I posted an answer which will eliminate one step of the process: copying the file from the remote server to your local server (the one you log in to directly).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your frustration is that using Remote Desktop adds an extra step to your normal workflow.

Here's a way to make manipulating a file on a remote computer more convenient.

Instead of using RDP to connect to your remote computer, and then opening explorer to find the file you're looking for, you can use explorer to connect remotely.

Open an explorer window, and type

```
\\remote-computer\c$
```

*remote-computer* should be the name of your remote computer, which is the same name that you use to connect with RDP. When you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it may ask you for credentials. Log-in with your username and password for the remote computer.

Now, you should be looking at the `C:\` drive on the remote computer. Navigate to the image file you want to use, as you normally would with

```
\\remote-computer\c$\path\to\my\images\folder
```

Now, you can use the files on your remote computer from your local computer.